# Two copies of windows on both of my drives

Tags: windows

I have 2 copies of Windows on my PC which is very odd.

When im trying to update my Windows from 19041 to 19042 it says I have to wipe my PC because it is in an unsupported directory. So I checked and I have the exact same windows files in my C: drive (my SSD) and in my D: drive (my HDD). I ran diskpart and list volume and it says boot is on C: drive.

So can I delete the d: drive one? And Any help on the unsupported directory?

Comment: One way to tell where the Windows you're currently using is running from would be to check the various system variables. Some of these point to the Windows directory and these should indicate which of the two installs you're actually using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a screenshot of Disk Manager showing the list of partition that exist on your disk

Comment: If you have no concept of a second windows in your mind, then you don't really have the skills to be deciding to delete one of them!  It's not necessarily odd to have two

Comment: Deleting an OS or partition is very risky for you, it's easy to delete the wrong one unless you have quite a bit of technical expertise. and check yourself properly.  Having two windows on a computer is excellent because if one goes bad you have another one to use. (though it also takes some expertise to be confident knowing how to switch between them)